# Pinning the Dock to a Corner in Yosemite/El Capitan

Tags: dock, macos

In Mavericks and prior, one could use the following commands to pin the dock to either the top or bottom corner of the screen, if the dock was placed left/right, or to the left/right corners if the dock was placed at the bottom, by using the following commands:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock pinning -string start
```

or

```
defaults write com.apple.dock pinning -string end
```

This is followed by `killall Dock` to restart the Dock. Now, in Yosemite, it appears that this option has been removed. Is there no way to get back this functionality in Yosemite?

**Update:** This is still not possible in El Capitan. Very disappointed in Apple.

Comment: Have you ran `killall dock`?

Comment: Yes, I ran that command too. Edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: Sorry, that's all I could find.

Comment: FWIW, the Dock's "Placement" setting in TinkerTool is disabled under Yosemite, further indication that it may simply not be possible. (Which makes me very, very sad.)

Comment: Sadly, it isn't looking like we can do it... perhaps if enough people complain to Apple about it?

Comment: Related [Apple Discussion post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6600902?start=0&tstart=0). Note that commenting on that thread will NOT help Apple hear you, but [filing a bug report](http://bugreporter.apple.com/) may.

Comment: This still seems to not be possible in 10.10.2. Very disappointed in Apple.

Comment: This still seems to not be possible in Sierra 10.12.4. Disappointed in Apple, but not very.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I filed bug #18701500 on this problem with http://bugreporter.apple.com/

My bug was closed by Apple Engineering as a duplicate of bug #16814560, which is still marked as open.

Although Apple does not permit public viewing of the bug database—I cannot see the details on the bug that they have closed it in favor of—and thus you cannot verify my statements, this is proof to me that there is currently no solution to this problem.

Comment: Apple's bug reporting is very frustrating but they do prioritize bugs based off of the number of reports. I have a feeling this will not be fixed but who knows.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this isn't possible as shown [here](http://thesweetsetup.com/os-x-dock-bottom-right/). Sorry.

Comment: I don't think that definitively shows it isn't possible, it's possible for instance that the option name has changed in Yosemite. But that's probably wishful thinking.

Comment: Yeah, well. Good luck.

Comment: If you ask for proof that reindeer can't fly, and I keep throwing them off the roof and they keep dying, it's true that each one only proves that **that** reindeer couldn't fly. However, each additional death suggests that none can. I, too, hold out hope, but it's dwindling.

Comment: Much disappointment.